# Do we use another "the" if a proper noun already begins with one?

Tags: grammar, repetition, doubled-words

> The lowest in-game rank of authority is that of the Baron – variations are Timariot, Shaman, Mayor, Bishop, Patrician – of which only Patrician is a playable rank if the player owns ***the The** Republic DLC*.

Is "**the The**" correct in the sentence, or should it just be "**The**"? DLC stands for downloadable content (in this case, a new place) in a game. It is the same idea as the following.

> - The New York Times is a good newspaper. We read ***the The*** New York Times.

Comment: No, just one *the* is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: "The Republic DLC" is not the name of a place; "The Republic" is the title of the downloadable content (DLC) pack that is being reviewed.

Comment: @Hellion Sorry, this was in regards to a disagreement I had with someone over this in a Wikipedia article [Crusader Kings II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusader_Kings_II), I'm not knowledgeable on the game. I do know what DLC is, I just didn't read that part of it very closely.

Comment: I don't think "the the" is any good, but I also don't think there is any rule of English that would license shortening the double "the" to a single "the".  Needing a double "the" is a trap that you have to find some way out of by finding a different way to say it.

Answer (score 10):

***[The](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/the)*** does work that only needs to be done once, as necessary, for each occurrence of a noun in a sentence:

> **definite article**
>
> 1. (used, especially before a noun, with a specifying or particularizing effect, as opposed to the indefinite or generalizing
>      force of the indefinite article a or an):
>
> *the book you gave me; Come into the house.*
>
> 2. (used to mark a proper noun, natural phenomenon, ship, building, time,
>      point of the compass, branch of endeavor, or field of study as
>      something well-known or unique):
>
> *the sun; the Alps; theQueen Elizabeth; the past; the West.*
>
> 3. (used with or as part of a title):
>
> the Duke of Wellington; the Reverend John Smith.
>
> 4. (used to mark a noun as indicating the best-known, most approved, most
>      important, most satisfying, etc.):
>
> *the skiing center of the U.S.; If you're going to work hard, now is the time.*
>
> 5. (used to mark a noun as being used generically):
>
> *The dog is a quadruped.*
>
> 6. (used in place of a possessive pronoun, to note a part of the body or
>      a personal belonging):
>
> *He won't be able to play football until the leg mends.*
>
> 7. (used before adjectives that are used substantively, to note an individual, a class or number of individuals, or an abstract idea):
>
> *to visit the sick; from the sublime to the ridiculous.*

If the name of an entity contains *The*, that entity has been identified **definitely** in its name, and the work of *the* is completed. No repetition is necessary.

---

dictionary.reference.com

Comment: What if it were "a *The Republic* DLC," if there were multiple? It seems that this article duplication would be warranted to specify that you're not referring to *all* of them or the *only* one. Then, by extension, if there were multiple, couldn't "the *The Republic* DLC" be correct—as in "The *The Republic* DLC currently on sale is the most popular ever"?

Comment: 'A copy of *The Republic DLC*' would be the correct phrasing

Comment: As others have concurred, an extra *the* is redundant, even if it is not **illegal**. More idiomatic expressions will make you look or sound a bit more intelligent: A version of The Republic; A copy of The Count of Monte Cristo; An issue of The NYT; The manuscript of The Count of Monte Cristo; The Count of Monte Cristo manuscript; The true NYT; The Republic DLC I. Of course if you wanted to emphasize its unique nature in spoken words, emphasizing ***The** The Republic DLC* does not carry a linguistic death penalty.

Comment: Also very often done in contexts where you need an indefinite article in front of a name that starts with a definite article is dropping the definite article from the name. So you’d have “a _Republic_ DLC”, “a New York Times cover”, “a _Count of Monte Cristo_ manuscript”, etc. (This doesn’t go for the band, of course—you have “a The The record”, but you also have “the The The record”.)

Comment: I disagree with the reasoning here.  There are two nouns that may be qualified: "Republic" and "DLC".  The first instance of "the" in the sentence qualifies "DLC" while the second qualifies "Republic".  While I would agree with the answer that only one is necessary, this is merely due to convention, not because of any real logic regarding unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Earth to @Jules! *The Republic* is a **D**own**L**oadable**C**ontent sequel of the **R**ole**P**laying**G**ame Crusader King, making it the RPG equivalent to *The Return of the King* in the *Lord of the Rings* movie trilogy. As an individual RPG it is *The Republic*; as a "level" of Crusader Kings, it is *The Republic*; as unique DLC it is still: *The Republic*. **The** DLC of **the** RPG Crusader Kings II: The Republic! We think it's great you enjoy playing in your imaginary world, but when you come back to the real world, lets speak a language we can all understand!

Comment: @ScotM Huh?  You haven't said anything in that comment that I didn't already know.  What are you saying I've got wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to say drop the first "the" as well, but as it's common practice to italicise titles of works, you could get away with "the *The Republic* DLC" (consider "the *The Count of Monte Cristo* manuscript").  I would still prefer to reword the sentence rather than use this approach, e.g. "...if the player owns the DLC 'The Republic'" or "...owns the DLC *The Republic*".

Answer (score 0):

'The The' is never correct except as the name of a [band](http://www.thethe.com/).

Comment: They stole the extra "the" from *Talking Heads*.